# Widget like as shortcut

Tags: android, widget

I have created a simple widget following the Android documentation itself. It consists of a color box and a text. Very simple. But I want the widget to be like the shortcuts to WhatsApp conversations: the application icon and a label text below. How can I make the widget like this?

What I want is to be able to create shortcuts like whatsapp:

[image]

As if it were an application icon instead of a widget.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you mean: when a user clicks on your widget the app open?

Comment: Yes, as WhatsApp does. If I create a shortcut to my friend Eddie's conversation, clicking opens this conversation.

Answer (score 0):

In your class widget inside updateAppWidget() you need to create a PendingIntent to the activity you wanted to be opened:

```
Intent intentOpenApp = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntentOpenApp = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intentOpenApp, 0);
```

And getting your views as:

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.app_widget);
```

Then set an click listener to it and pass your PendingIntent

```
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.your_textview, pendingIntentOpenApp);
```

Don't forget to notify your widget manager to update the widget

```
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
```

Comment: I add an image in the post